# NuSOAP / fsockopen error - Couldn't open socket connection to server , Error (13): Permission denied

Tags: soap, apache, nusoap, fsockopen

I have a php application using NuSOAP on a RHEL5/CentOS dedicated system.

I'm runing into the following error:

```
2010-10-21 06:23:43.374471 soap_transport_http: entered send() with data of length: 1693
2010-10-21 06:23:43.374510 soap_transport_http: connect connection_timeout 0, response_timeout 30, scheme http, host www.mysite.com, port 2194
2010-10-21 06:23:43.374557 soap_transport_http: calling fsockopen with host www.mysite.com connection_timeout 0
2010-10-21 06:23:43.700553 soap_transport_http: Couldn't open socket connection to server http://www.mysite.com:2194/webservice.event, Error (13): Permission denied
2010-10-21 06:23:43.700719 nusoap_client: Error: HTTP Error: Couldn't open socket connection to server http://www.mysite.com:2194/webservice.event, Error (13): Permission denied
```

I think its related to some httpd configuration - as per http://www.linuxdevelop.com/redhat--fedora-linux-help/fsockopen-error-13-permission-denied-24366.shtml

> I found the problem was related to
>   SELinux configuration.
>
> The firewall is enabled on my server:
>   policy type is targeted, enforcing
>   current is checked and HTTPD scripts
>   to connect to the network were not
>   allowed.
>
> Where: Desktop > System Settings >
>   Security Level > SELinux > httpd >
>   HTTPD scripts to connect to the
>   network was unchecked.  I checked it
>   and it is working now.

But I wasnt able to find how to modify this directly within the httpd.conf file

Comment: did you find a solution?? Having the same issue where i am transferring some php/nusoap files to another server :(

Answer (score 5):

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

check this url: http://yml.com/fv-b-1-619/selinux--apache-httpd--php-establishing-socket-connections-using-fsockopen---et-al.html

Comment: You have no idea how many upvotes you deserve. That was an interesting  boolean to dig into. Thanks a lot!